# Android - Running a delayed task from a Worker Thread (NotificationListenerService Thread)

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to call a delayed method(runnable) from the NLService thread. However the method never gets called. I would appreciate any help.

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    if(sbn.getPackageName().contains("mv.purple.aa")){

       AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
       amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);

       //This is the code I am having issues with.
       //I used this code to call the method. However it is not working.
       private Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

    }


}

//I want to call the following method
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    foobar();
 }
};

}
```

Comment: Is 'onNotificationPosted(...)' called? Is your package name correct?

Comment: please be more specific: which isn't called? The method, the if block,etc

Comment: Yes @PhilippJahoda ,'onNotificationPosted(...)' gets called.

Comment: @cbrulak , thanks for pointing that out. I have added comments in the code where I need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NotificationListenerService` is a service which gets activated when notifications are posted within the framework.  It does this via a `Binder` notification internal to the framework, so your `onNotificationPosted()` callback is being called from one of the binder pool threads, not the usual main thread of your app.  In essence, the `Handler` you are creating is associating itself with a `Looper` which never gets called because the thread is managed by the internal binder framework rather than the usual main thread or other thread you may create.

Try this: create a HandlerThread the first time your callback is hit (and save it off) and start it.  Toss your `Runnable` over to a `Handler` you create which is bound to the `Looper` in the `HandlerThread`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a "simpler" solution.
You can create a new `Handler` inside your `onCreate()`. Save it as class variable and call it when ever you want again.

Example:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService
    private mHandler handler;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something special here :)
            }
        }, 5*1000); 
    }
   ....
   // Override other importand methods
   ....
}
```